# only this jquery script not working in ie11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

i wrote this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").on("click",function(){
       var color = $(this).css("background-color");
        $(this).parent().css({'border':'4px solid',color,'border-radius':'8px'});
        var color_code = "<p style='color:black;font-size:15px;padding:15px;font-family:calibri'>"+color+"</p>"
        $(this).replaceWith(color_code)

    });
});

</script>
```

works fine on all browser except ie 11, i dont know what the problem could be? any suggestion? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IE doesn't skip your mistake inside brackets:

```
 {'border':'4px solid',color,'border-radius':'8px'}
```

Should be:

```
 {'border':'4px solid ' + color, 'border-radius':'8px'}
```

Comment: hi, the value color is not for the background but for the border. i try with {'border':'4px solid'+color,'border-radius':'8px'} but this not work in other browser as well

Comment: ok i solved, i'm a bit tired today :) - i wrote: {'border':'4px solid','border-color': color, 'border-radius':'8px'}